# How to display confidence intervals coorrectly with multiple stats in tbl_summary

Tags: r, gtsummary, gt

I have the follow code to display multiple statistics. I need to display the confidence interval too, but the code display the CI in the wrong line, I would like to display in same line that `mean(sd)` are displayed.

```
library(gtsummary)
iris %>% 
  select(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width,Species) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = Species,
              type = all_continuous() ~ "continuous2",
              statistic = all_continuous() ~ c(
                "{mean} ({sd})",
                "{median} ({p25}, {p75})",
                "{min}, {max}"
              ),
              missing = "no", digits = everything() ~ 1) %>% 
  add_ci(include = all_continuous(),
         statistic = all_continuous()~ "{conf.low}, {conf.high}")
```

Result table:

[image]

Table I want:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is an argument within `add_ci()` to get what you need; but we can modify the output and shift the CI columns down.

```r
library(gtsummary)

iris %>% 
  select(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width,Species) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = Species,
              type = all_continuous() ~ "continuous2",
              statistic = all_continuous() ~ c(
                "{mean} ({sd})",
                "{median} ({p25}, {p75})",
                "{min}, {max}"
              ),
              missing = "no", digits = everything() ~ 1) %>% 
  add_ci(include = all_continuous(),
         statistic = all_continuous()~ "{conf.low}, {conf.high}") -> summary_table

for (x in paste0("ci_stat_", 1:3)) {
    summary_table$table_body[[x]] <- dplyr::lag(summary_table$table_body[[x]])
 }

summary_table
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>